# Is there a way to a get a list of all address tags from Blockchain.com? (either by scrapping or API)

Tags: address, exchanges, identity

I am looking to get the most complete list of address association with entity names.
I am thinking blockchain.com must have a good one but here *https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tags?filter=8&offset=500* you can only search by address or name and not get a complete list.
Is there a way to get it?
Does another website give access to a good list?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [walletexplorer](https://www.walletexplorer.com/).
Or start compiling this list yourself, there is a ton of false data there. So if you are looking for quantity, I'd suggest walletexplorer, for quality you have to do attribute these services on your own.